# Memory is not coming down after data processing in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using broadcastprocess function to perform simple pattern matching. I am broadcasting around 60 patterns. Once the process completed the memory is not coming down i am using garbage collection setting in my flink configuration file `env.java.opts = "-XX:+UseG1GC"` to perform GC but it is also not working. But CPU percentage coming after completing the processing of data. I am doing checkpointing every 2 minutes and my statebackend is filesystem. Below are screenshots of memory and CPU usage

[image]

[image]

Comment: To clarify: the graphs are showing resource utilization by the one and only task manager? And the job in question was streaming job that has been stopped or canceled, or is it still running?

Comment: @DavidAnderson thanks for the reply, the graph is entire cluster resource but if you see the memory utilization after 50-75% it is being used by pattern matching resources. The problem here for every round data it is receiving the memory is increasing and final it touches 100% and pods will crash. After processing the data the memory is not coming down. The graph is of a running streaming job.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything surprising or problematic in the graphs you have shared. After ingesting the patterns, each instance of your BroadcastProcessFunction will be holding onto a copy of all of the patterns -- so that will consume some memory.

If I understand correctly, it sounds like the situation is that as data is processed for matching against those patterns, the memory continues to increase until the pods crash with out-of-memory errors. Various factors might explain this:

- If your patterns involve matching a sequence of events over time, then your pattern matching engine has to keep state for each partial match. If there's no timeout clause to ensure that partial matches are eventually cleaned up, this could lead to a combinatorial explosion.
- If you are doing key-partitioned processing and your keyspace is unbounded, you may be holding onto state for stale keys.
- The filesystem state backend has considerable overhead. You may have underestimated how much memory it needs.

Comment: I am not holding events in memory or i am not using key-partitioned processing in my use case. I am receiving simple json objects in which i am looking for a particular is satisfying my condition or not. I need to check filesystem state backend.

Comment: If you aren't doing anything keyed, then the state backend is probably not the issue. What version of Flink is this?

Comment: I am using flink version 1.10.0

Comment: Between the bug fix releases 1.10.1, 1.10.2, and 1.10.3, a total of 267 bugs were fixed. I suggest upgrading to see if that helps.